# First timer on StackOverflow---Having trouble with recursion. Trying to have the computer recursively guess the user's number

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having a little trouble with this program. I'm a newbie to recursion by the way. Anyway I'm running this and i feel like it should work but it just becomes an infinite loop. Error message is "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison". I'm just taking a number, upper and lower limit from the user and having the computer guess it recursively. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## game where computer guesses user's number using recursion

```
import random as rand
def recursionNum(compGuess, magicNum):
   #if the number that the user inputs for the computer to 
   #guess is to low it multiplies the number by 2 and then subtracts 1
   #if the number is to high its divided(//) by 2 and then adds 1
  if compGuess == magicNum: 
      print('You guessed right')   #basecase
  elif compGuess > magicNum:
      print('Guess is', compGuess, '...Lower')
      return recursionNum(compGuess //2+1, magicNum)    
  else:
      print('Guess is', compGuess,'....Higher')
      return recursionNum(compGuess *2-1, magicNum)
userNum =0
lowerLim = 0
upperLim = 0
while userNum not in range(lowerLim, upperLim):
  lowerLim = int(input('What your lower limit: '))
  upperLim = int(input('What is yor upper limit: '))  
  userNum = int(input('pick a number within your set limits:'))
compGuess = rand.randint in range(lowerLim, upperLim)
recursionNum(compGuess, userNum)
```

Comment: If you're using an up-to-date version of Python, and hopefully you are, did you take into account that dividing a number by two can result in a fractional number?

Comment: Why does your function have a `magicNum` parameter that's never used anywhere?

Comment: oops there ya go, line 3 and 6. Forgot to change userNum to magicNum

Comment: @Aran-Fey line 3 and line 6

Comment: @matti virkkunen, ahhh yes that is right. like if the compGuess = 9 so it takes the 9 and divides by 2 giving me 4.5....that is a problem lol. Still trying to get it together. How could i fix that

Comment: You can use `//` for integer division but that doesn't necessarily solve the entire problem.

Comment: its giving me errors for line 10 and line 13.

Comment: ile "C:/Users/Kendall/Desktop/recursion assignment.py", line 20, in <module>
    recursionNum(compGuess, userNum)

Comment: assignment.py", line 10, in recursionNum

Comment: assignment.py", line 13, in recursionNum @Matti Virkkunen

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will never print anything because the print statement is after the return. Return returns control back to the calling scope and so lines following a return statement are ignored. Second, there is no reason to use recursion for this. A simple for loop is much better suited for this. If you are just looking for an application to practice recursion on, may I suggest a Fibonacci number generator? It is a fairly popular example for the topic.

Comment: Yea, and i understand those more too, but i was told to use recursion.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but for the conversation above you can fix the float result from division by just using int().

Comment: How so, like this? Still trying to fully understand the syntax sorry.        -------return recursionNum(int(compGuess /2+1, magicNum)) @Christian.M

Comment: No like this ------ return recursionNum(int(compGuess/2)+1, magicNum)

Comment: Forgot about it, but Matti gave the better answer above with using //

Comment: yes. compGuess//2 is the same thing as int(compGuess/2) but it is the more pythonic syntax.